# Quick way to compute Ehrhart polynomial of Young diagram posets?

Tags: co.combinatorics, convex-polytopes, posets

Using the hook formula, it is easy to compute the volume of order polytopes obtained from *posets with partition shape*, since this is the same as the number of linear extensions.

To my knowledge, computing the number of linear extensions of an *arbitrary* order polytope is #P-hard.

There is also the family of series-parallel posets, where computing the Ehrhart polynomial (and hence the volume) can be done in polynomial time, so there are natural families where computing the Ehrhart polynomial is easy.

**My question is then:** can one compute the Ehrhart polynomial of partition-shaped order polytopes quickly (and not just the volume)?

[image: Poset]

Comment: Isn't this equivalent to counting $P$-partitions of bounded maximal size? For this there is a determinantal formula known to MacMahon later generalized to skew shapes by Kreweras.

Comment: See the note on pg 23 of: http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9908029v1.

Comment: @SamHopkins: Ah, right, that makes sense!

Comment: Of course, I should've just said "plane partitions" above, which is what $P$-partitions are in this case of $P$ :)

Answer (score 1):

The number of plane partitions of shape $\lambda/\mu$
with maximal entry at most $m$, is given by
$$
\det\left(
\binom{\lambda_i-\mu_j + m}{i-j+m}
\right)_{i,j=1,\dotsc,\ell}
$$
where $\ell = \ell(\lambda)$.

See *Kreweras, Germain. Sur une classe de problèmes de dénombrement liés au treillis des partitions des entiers.*

Comment: I saw this pop up and was about to point out that the case of straight shapes actually goes back to MacMahon, and then I saw my own comments from 4 years ago. :)

Comment: By the way, a nice proof of this is via the Lindstrom-Gessel-Viennot lemma.